# Combine rows of a column based on index range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe with one column.

```
Index | column1 |
0         and
1         too
2         ask
3         the
4         but
5         hat
6         hot
7         top
8         tap
```

I would like to combine rows between indices based on a condition. For example, if a row has the letter 'a', the indices would be:

```
0, 2, 5, 8
```

therefore, combining rows:

```
(0, 1), (2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7), (8)
```

Finally the output being:

```
Index | column1 |
0         and, too
1         ask, the, but
2         hat, hot, top
3         tap
```

What I have tried is:

```
[i for i in range(len(df['column1'])) if 'a' in df['column1'][i]]
```

gives me the indices:

```
[0, 2, 5, 8]
```

but stuck from here. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare by `a` with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and create groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then remove possible first group contains non `a` values by filtering `g[g > 0]` and last aggregate with `join`:

```
g = df['column1'].str.contains('a').cumsum()

df = df.groupby(g[g > 0])['column1'].apply(', '.join).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
print (df)
         column1
0       and, too
1  ask, the, but
2  hat, hot, top
3            tap
```

First value not contains `a`:

```
print (df)
  column1
1     too
2     ask
3     the
4     but
5     hat
6     hot
7     top
8     tap

g = df['column1'].str.contains('a').cumsum()

df = df.groupby(g[g > 0])['column1'].apply(', '.join).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
print (df)
         column1
0  ask, the, but
1  hat, hot, top
2            tap
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stuff=["and","too","ask","the","but","hat","hot","top","tap"]

newlist=[]
collection=[]
for i in stuff:
    if "a" in i:
        if len(collection) >0:
            newlist.append(collection)
        collection=[]
    collection.append(i)
newlist.append(collection)
```

try some thing like this